# S&P 500 index actual official stock weights

Tags: data-request, finance

Where can I found on https://spglobal.com `S&P 500` index actual official stock weights.

Answer (score 1):

I found one source that has the data as an html table.

https://www.slickcharts.com/sp500

You can use pandas to parse the html table as a dataframe, and then write a csv:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

df = pd.read_html(requests.get('https://www.slickcharts.com/sp500',
                      headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text)[0]

print(df)
df.to_csv('sp.csv',index=False)
```

And here's the data as of 2021-05-06

https://gist.github.com/philshem/f2fc94d7e49f045fe0feda8532ab2c08#file-sp-csv

Comment: I know about slickchart, but I search official information. Thanks anyway for the answer.